# JS filter doesn't work properly when filtering an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, object

In my react native application, I have the following array.

```
export const ID_OPTIONS = [
  { id: 'nric_fin', name: 'NRIC/FIN' },
  { id: 'passport', name: 'Passport' },
  { id: 'birth_cert', name: 'Birth Certificate' },
];
```

I tried to filter this array as follows.

```
setSelectedIdType = (idType) => {
  return ID_OPTIONS.filter((type) => {
    if (type.id === idType) {
      return type.name;
    }
    return null;
  });
}
```

But, this return an object. I want to get the name as the result. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: filter return type is used as a boolean to determine if the current element should stay or not. What do you want your function to do? the name is confusing, its not setting anything just finding something. Do you want only the name returned? an array of names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) just use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) since `filter` returns the filtered array instead of one item. `Array.find` returns the first matched item on which you can then take the `name`:

As per `Array.filter` docs - **return value**:

> A new array with the elements that pass the test. If no elements pass
>   the test, an empty array will be returned.

And in regards to the `test` function which `Array.filter` executes per each iteration:

> Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return
>   **true** to keep the element, **false** otherwise.

Note that the return value is **boolean**.

With `Array.find` your function could just be:

```js
const ID_OPTIONS = [ { id: 'nric_fin', name: 'NRIC/FIN' }, { id: 'passport', name: 'Passport' }, { id: 'birth_cert', name: 'Birth Certificate' }, ];

let setSelectedIdType = idType => 
  (ID_OPTIONS.find(x => x.id === idType) || {}).name

console.log(setSelectedIdType('nric_fin'))
console.log(setSelectedIdType('passport'))
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks more like you’re looking for a for loop:

```
setSelectedIdType = (idType) => {
  for (let type of ID_OPTIONS) {
    if (type.id === idType) {
      return type.name;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

The equivalent can be implemented using `find`:

```
setSelectedIdType = (idType) => {
  let type = ID_OPTIONS.find(type => type.id === idType);
  return type && type.name;
}
```

(This returns `undefined` instead of `null` when the id isn’t found; something like `type === undefined ? null : type.name` will change that if necessary.)

Answer (score 3):

A `filter` filters elements out of an array... it doesn't matter what you are returning exactly, the return value will be treated simply as either "truthy" or "falsy" (elements for which the function returns a "truthy" value are kept, others are discarded).

All non-empty strings are "truthy" in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Just `map` the array afterwards to get the `name`.

```
return ID_OPTIONS.filter(...).map(({ name }) => name);
```

You could alternatively use `reduce` to reduce complexity:

```
setSelectedIdType = idType => ID_OPTIONS.reduce((a, { id, name }) => id == idType ? (a.push(name), a) : a, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [Mozilla Filter Function Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

`callback`
    Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return true to keep the element, false otherwise.

`Return value`
A new array with the elements that pass the test. If no elements pass the test, an empty array will be returned.

I dont think callback for filter can be other than boolean
while the return value should be an array containing the matched result from the filter function

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary for your domain to store the objects in a array?

Since you've declared them as constants I'm going to make the assumption that they won't change unless the client is reloaded.

If you were to transform this array of objects into a simple object like so:

```
const NAMES = ID_OPTIONS.reduce((obj,idOption) => {
  obj[idOption.id] = {name: idOption.name};
  return obj;
},{});
```

which will result in:

```
{
  nric_fin: {name: 'NRIC/FIN'},
  passport: {name: 'Passport'},
  birth_cert: { name: 'Birth Certificate'}
}
```

and now you access the name by property

```
let idType = 'passport';
NAMES[idType];
```